# Python: Install VirtualEnv for both Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

After moving over to Fedora (from Windows), I realized that it came with both installations of Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.6.6.

As I familiarized myself with using Python, I learned of the great utilities of virtual environments and how organized they keep everything.

However, my current dilemma is for which Python version should I do `pip(2 or 3) install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper`.

From my research, I understand that the `virtualenvwrapper` provides the ability to create a virtual environment using a specified version of Python: `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python(2 or 3) {name}`.

Therefore, should I only install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` on one of the Python versions and use the aforementioned feature? Or should I install `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` on both versions of Python.

Would there be any conflicts?

**Edit**

More importantly, assuming that I have `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` installed for both Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.6.6, which version's command is called when I run any of the following: `workon`, `mkvirtualenv`, `rmvirtualenv`, etc.?

Comment: You can install both, but any new Python development should use Python3 anyway. There will be no conflicts until you try to run code written for Python3 in python2 virtualenv

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for the response! It makes sense and I think I understand better now. But I've made an edit to my question above, purely out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would there be any conflicts?

Not until you mistakenly run the default system `python` command with a script that's using the opposite version as compared to the more specific python2 or python3 commands.

The virtualenvs do not conflict, and must be activated to be used. You can also of course have as many virtualenv's as you wish.

To avoid any problems setting up an environment, its suggested to run `python2 -m virtualenv` for example, rather than simply virtualenv command itself

For the commands listed at the bottom of the question, it depends on how your PATH is configured. Personally, I use pyenv rather than virtualenv directly, which injects itself into the OS PATH variable